# fileDownload.js jQuery plugin and PHP headers

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using this great [jquery.fileDownload.js](https://github.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload) plugin to allow users to download self-generated CSV files from my website.

From what I understood, based in the PHP code from [this site](https://github.com/seiko777/PHP-jquery-downloader/blob/master/download.php) (suggested by fileDownload creator), I need to set a cookie to identify when the download is sucessfull or not:

```
try {
    $page = file_get_contents($filepath);
    echo $page;
    header('Set-Cookie: fileDownload=true; path=/');
} catch(Exception $e) {
    header('Set-Cookie: fileDownload=false; path=/');   
}
```

It works as expected when `fileDownload=true`, but fail event is never fired when `fileDownload=false`.

Here is my javascript code:

```
$.fileDownload('export.php')
    .done(function() {
        alert('Done!');
    })
    .fail(function() {
        alert('Fail!');
    });
```

And here is my **export.php** code:

```
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Content-type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.csv"');
try {
    // Code for generating the CSV file
    header('Set-Cookie: fileDownload=true; path=/'); 
} catch(Exception $e) {
    header('Set-Cookie: fileDownload=false; path=/');   
}
exit;
```

When file is generated correcly I got the success message, but never get the fail message, even when simulating an issue.

Please, what I am missing? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the cookie is only used to [check if a download was completed](https://github.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload/blob/master/src/Scripts/jquery.fileDownload.js#L356), but not to assess failure. But it does [catch HTTP errors](https://github.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload/blob/master/src/Scripts/jquery.fileDownload.js#L423), so the solution is simply sending a 500 from the server:

```
try {
    $page = file_get_contents($filepath);
    echo $page;
    header('Set-Cookie: fileDownload=true; path=/');
} catch(Exception $e) {
    http_response_code(500); 
}
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly setting a HTTP response error code didn't work either, the fail event is never fired. I am trying to understand the source but my javascript/jquery knoledge is limited... Please, do you know how can I debug the javascript code? Is there a free Windows application for this? Thanks!

Comment: That is very strange. What happens on failure? Does it alert 'Done!' or does nothing happen? As for debugging: Both Firefox' and Google Chrome's developer tools have excellent JS debugging built in.

Comment: For testing purposes I added `header('Set-Cookie: fileDownload=false; path=/'); exit;` and also `http_response_code(500); exit;` in the begining of the export.php file, but nothing happens. When I remove this lines and the file is downloaded, I got the "Done!" message as expected. I will try to use the browser debugger. Thanks!

Comment: Try replacing `export.php` with `https://httpstat.us/500`. This URL gives a HTTP 500. If the alert triggers, there's something wrong in the PHP. Also open the Chrome/FF developer toolbar in the Network tab and see if your export.php actually sends a 500.

Comment: Also, make sure the plugin is up to date. the `.fail()` callback works on their demo site with HTTP 500. Also, instead of the callback you could try using the `failMessageHtml` option with jQuery UI

Comment: Well, I double checked the plugin version and made several tests, using Chrome debugger, and now it is working!! I do not know exctly what I did, but I think there is something related with the PHP file encoding (I changed from ANSI to UTF-8)... I also included an `echo '&nbsp;';` after the `header('Set-Cookie: fileDownload=false; path=/');` and before the `exit;`. Thank you again for your tips, they helped a lot!